# How to make sure the number of columns in CSS grid is a factor of the number of columns?

Tags: css, http

I would like to make sure that for all browser sizes the last row in a CSS grid has an equal number of items as the other rows in the grid.

At the moment I have tried using a repeat with auto-fill and a minmax function, setting the max as 4fr. I am trying to display 8 images but if the browser shrinks that four columns at least the size of the minimum can't fit, and it does 3 columns instead then the last row only has two which looks ugly.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="img/img_1.png">
  <img src="img/img_2.png">
  <img src="img/img_3.png">
  <img src="img/img_4.png">
  <img src="img/img_5.png">
  <img src="img/img_6.png">
  <img src="img/img_7.png">
  <img src="img/img_8.png">
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(350px, 4fr));
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    justify-items: center;
}

.container > img {
    object-fit: stretch;
    height: 350px;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Ideally would like it such that if three images in a row can fit it does 2 in each row, with the images positioned centrally in the row.

Currently:

```html
<img><img><img>
<img><img><img>
<img><img>
```

Would like:

```html
  <img><img>  
  <img><img>  
  <img><img>  
  <img><img>
```

Comment: Ar you set on not using JavaScript for this?

Comment: Not possible with CSS as it can't count child elements...you need JS.

Comment: Haven't learnt JS yet, so was trying to do it with just HTML and CSS